# Drop a column if all the values are a specific value

Tags: r

I would like to drop a column if it has all the cells with `No Items`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(cat =   c(1,1,1,"No items",2,2,2,"No items"),
                  item1 = c(0,0,1,0,1,1,"No items",0),
                  item2 = c("No items","No items","No items","No items","No items","No items","No items","No items"),
                  item3 = c(0,0,1,"No items",1,0,0,0))

> df1
       cat    item1    item2    item3
1        1        0 No items        0
2        1        0 No items        0
3        1        1 No items        1
4 No items        0 No items No items
5        2        1 No items        1
6        2        1 No items        0
7        2 No items No items        0
8 No items        0 No items        0
```

In this case I need to drop `item2` column. The desired output would be:

```
> df1
       cat    item1    item3
1        1        0        0
2        1        0        0
3        1        1        1
4 No items        0 No items
5        2        1        1
6        2        1        0
7        2 No items        0
8 No items        0        0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. `base` solution with `Filter()`:**

```
Filter(function(x) !all(x == "No items"), df1)
```

**2. `purrr` solution with `keep()` and `discard()`:**

```
library(purrr)

## Option 1 : keep
keep(df1, ~ !all(.x == "No items"))

## Option 2 : discard
discard(df1, ~ all(.x == "No items"))
```

**3. `dplyr` solution with `select()`:**

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% select(where(~ !all(.x == "No items")))
```

---

***Output***

```
#        cat    item1    item3
# 1        1        0        0
# 2        1        0        0
# 3        1        1        1
# 4 No items        0 No items
# 5        2        1        1
# 6        2        1        0
# 7        2 No items        0
# 8 No items        0        0
```

Comment: thanks! where() in your third option is not in my library but your first solution works just great!

Comment: @amisos55 `where()` is one of new functions in `dplyr 1.0.0`. You can update your package version to use it.

Answer (score 3):

A `base R` approach,

```
df1[,colSums(df1 == "No items") != nrow(df1)]
```

gives,

```
       cat    item1    item3
1        1        0        0
2        1        0        0
3        1        1        1
4 No items        0 No items
5        2        1        1
6        2        1        0
7        2 No items        0
8 No items        0        0
```